# Is it possible to access sessionStorage from handlebars?

Tags: ember.js

```
{{#if sessionStorage.getItem("isLogin")}}
    <div class="header-item" ><h4 id="logout_button" {{action 'logout' on='click'}}>Logout</h4> </div>
  {{else}}
    <div class="header-item" id="signup_button">{{#link-to 'signup' tagName='h4'}}  Sign Up {{/link-to}}</div>
    <div class="header-item" id="login_button">{{#link-to 'login' tagName='h4'}}  Login {{/link-to}}</div>
  {{/if}}
```

above code throwing error

Answer (score 2):

You’ll need to expose `sessionStorage` to the template via the controller or component, depending on the context here. Assuming you’re on Octane, you could define a getter like this:

```
get isLogin() {
  return window.sessionStorage.getItem('isLogin');
}
```

There are also addons that integrate `localStorage` and `sessionStorage`, such as [Ember localStorage](https://github.com/funkensturm/ember-local-storage).

Comment: This approach has the drawback of not updating when `sessionStorage` changes. UI and state can get out of sync. Hard to debug. To avoid that issue a more advanced solution needs to listen to `storage` event and invalidate `isLogin` when `isLogin` item in `sessionStorage` changes.